# What is ctag in javascript loaded files in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, browser, web-inspector

When I inspect a webpage I can see javascript files with name and a query string attached to their name. Like: jquery-1.9.1.min.js?ctag=0$$16.0.4230.1217.

I googles ctag but didn't find anything useful which I can understand.

I want to know what is the difference between files with ctag and without it?
(*jquery-1.9.1.min.js* **vs.** *jquery-1.9.1.min.js?ctag=0$$16.0.4230.1217*)

[image]

Comment: it allow the browser to download a new version if  a new is available instead of get the file from the cache

Comment: Can you paste the link of the page where you found this?

Comment: I am developing a website in the SharePoint online which you may not be able to access but I made an screenshot and uploaded here: http://imgh.us/javascript_ctag.png

Comment: see my updated answer, sharepoint add the `ctag` parameter,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see http parameters added to the end of a script url it's usually for one of two reasons.

1. To cache the script in the browser.
   Usually a version number is added, the cache can then be forced to update by changing the version. i.e.

`http://example.com/js/myscrpt.js?ver=0.4`

2. To send data to the server.
   It might be that the script being returned is actually generated server side and the parameter is sending a value that is used in the generation of that script. i.e.

`http://example.com/js/myscript.js?userid=935284025805`

UPDATE: searching the web, it seems that links deployed on Sharepoint using JSLINK adds a `ctag` parameter to the urls of javascript files. It's possible the link is from a Sharepoint site, see [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115915/why-redeploying-jslink-file-adds-a-ctag-to-it) and [here](http://www.balestra.be/2013/06/quick-fix-sharepoint-2013-cant-find-localised-customstrings-js.html) for Sharepoint questions about the added `ctag`

Comment: How do know it is used for caching? `ctag` is a tool that is used for extracting symbols from source code, so that editors can show suggestions to the programmer. In the URL it is set to `0`. Maybe if you set it to `1` you will get different output. It may just be a convenience thing for the developer that wrote the code.

Comment: it might not have been the developers intention to put it in the url, it may indeed be a tool he/she is using, however in the example and usage the OP is asking about the parameter will causing the script to cache, regardless of the initial intent. How would the usage asked about be any use to an editor like vim?